# How can I extend two classes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to extend two classes having with keyword in flutter to get SearchDelegate override methods but can't do so. Please suggest any solution.

```
class A extends StatefulWidget with SearchDelegate{}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Normally, you can easily call multiple classes (inheritance) in dart using the 'with' keyword, like

```
Class A extends B with C, D {
    //your code
}
```

But when u call SearchDelegate you may see

***The class 'SearchDelegate' can't be used as a mixin because it declares a constructor.***

***The class 'SearchDelegate' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object.***

**Short Explanation:**  Here, u have to override all its abstract methods, as well as you need to pass a String/int variable in your declared class. That means, you might have to call DataSearch class constructor with the needed variable

Because of calling the constructor with-param, it would be better to call a new class where you can implement SearchDelegate easily.

Like for any button action

```
onPressed: () {
        showSearch(
          context: context,
          delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(),
        );
      },
```

I hope, my answer make a sense to you.
Thanks